# Trying to Convert from decimal to binary and it is not working C#

Tags: c#

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input decimal number to convert");
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int count = 0;
            int[] binary = { };
            while (num != 0)
            {
                int answer = num % 2;
                binary[count] = answer;
                count++;
                num /= 2;
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
            for (int i = binary.Length; i < binary.Length && i >= 0; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(binary[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Update the question with some sample inputs, what it outputs and what the expected output would be and you'll have a better chance of getting some answers.

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values of the variables at the time?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: Well, you try to parse an integer, not the decimal, in this line `int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` Please, add the expected result and exact problem with your code

Answer (score 1):

"Not working" is not a programmer term. When asking questions on Stackoverflow, you should provide far more detail as to what exactly is going wrong.

Looks like there are a number of different issues with your code. Hard to know where to start. Here's how I would write my own C# code to convert an integer to a binary string:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

if (num == 0)
{
    builder.Append('0');
}
else
{
    while (num != 0)
    {
        builder.Insert(0, (char)('0' + (num & 1)));
        num >>= 1;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Or `string output = Convert.ToString(num, 2);` or `string.Concat(Convert.ToString(num, 2).Reverse());` if it actually needs to be reversed.

Comment: @Jimi: Sure, but as I indicated this is how I'd write my own C# code to convert it (as opposed to using existing code).

Comment: The *note* is more related to the OP's expected output, hence *if it actually needs to be reversed*. The bits representation is reversed, here. I was wondering if this is really the expected outcome (the question is missing a real description, so...).